# WooCommerce iOS OAuth Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, objective-c, wordpress, oauth, woocommerce

Many people have been tearing their hair out looking for a solution to the invalid signature issue when sending requests to the WooCommerce api from an iOS app.

I have put together the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing the solution for the invalid signature issue when sending requests to the WooCommerce API from an iOS app.

To use WooCommerce in the iOS app, the requests must authenticate using OAuth 1.0. In iOS, regardless of whether the app is being written in Objective-C or Swift, AFNetworking makes life easier when writing requests.

Follow this procedure to setup your requests:

1. Get the URL, OAuth 1.0 Consumer key and consumer secret ready.
2. Add AFNetworking to your project using Cocoapods. Your podfile will look like this:

   ```
     source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
     platform :ios, '9.0'

     target 'OAuthSample3' do
         use_frameworks!

         # Pods for OAuthSample3
         pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.4'
     end
   ```

   Save this in your project directory and run `pod install` in terminal.
   For the next step, we must install AFNetworking 1.3.4. That's why it says 1.3.4 in the podfile.
3. Next, download this project from github: https://github.com/khanghoang/-WooClient
   Unzip it and copy `AFOAuth1Client.h`, `AFOAuth1Client.m`, `AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.h`, `AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.m`, `AFOAuth1OneLeggedClientWooParser.h`, `AFOAuth1OneLeggedClientWooParser.m` to your project.
4. Now we need to modify these files a bit. Open `AFOAuth1Client.h` and find the `AFHMACSHA1Signature()` method.
   Look for these lines:

   ```
     // one-legged
     if(![secret isEqualToString:@""]) {
         secretString = [secretString stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@", AFPercentEscapedQueryStringPairMemberFromStringWithEncoding(secret, stringEncoding)];
     }
   ```

   And replace them with:

   ```
     // one-legged  
     secretString = [secretString stringByAppendingFormat:@"&"];
   ```
5. That's it! This will solve the issue.

In your view controller you could make the request like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient *client = [[AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PATH] key:OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY secret:OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET];

    [client getPath:@"orders" parameters:@{} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

You could add parameters in the dictionary. The `OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY` and `OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET` must be replaced by the values you gathered in the first step.

You could also do this in Swift. Just use a bridging header to import the AFNetworking files.

Many thanks to khanghoang for the breakthrough in AFOAuth1Client.

Comment: I am looking for the API call to woo commerce in ios, i have used your code but getting error 401,

    {"code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_error","message":"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match."

Comment: Step 4 not possible

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer to @Akilan Arasu for  Swift solution to "List Products" in WooCommerce

Follow the first four steps of above solution and to list products from WooCommerce 5th step in swift will be

```
    let client = AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.init(baseURL: NSURL(string:"http://example.com/wc-api/v3/"), key: "ck_xxxxxx ",secret: "cs_xxxxx")


    client.getPath("products", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, responseObject  ) in
        let responseArray = responseObject as? NSDictionary
        print(responseArray)
        let product = responseArray?.valueForKey("products") as! NSArray

        print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)


        }, failure: { (operation, error) in
            print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)


    })
```

Comment: What files did you import in the bridging header file? I get to see some error

Comment: @Sid I have added AFOAuth1Client.h, AFOAuth1Client.m, AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.h, AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.m, AFOAuth1OneLeggedClientWooParser.h, AFOAuth1OneLeggedClientWooParser.m these files manually from the zipped file from https://github.com/khanghoang/-WooClient and there would be AFOAuth1OneLeggedClientTests, and other tests files in it..So just neglect those.. and also added #import "AFOAuth1Client.h"
#import "AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.h"
#import "AFOAuth1OneLeggedClientWooParser.h" in the bridging header

Comment: Did you update  i. the search path's for the bridging header file ii. Add afnetworking to the link binary section in the build phase iii. Search for header paths. Any of these?

Comment: I have manually installed the AFNetworking1.3.4 (added #import "AFNetworking.h" in bridging Header)
and WooClient.. So there is no such updates needed for me, It worked well with Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2, following the below @Akilan Arasu instructions and change the 5th step to the above..

Comment: AFOAuth1OneLegged not a function/has no init

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient'