# Upload image using AFHTTP.client in swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, image-uploading

I am using AFNetworking 1.3.3 and I had functions related to  AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient which uses the AFHTTP.client.h in old AFNetworking.So I could not update to latest AFNetworking. Now I need to upload an image using AFHTTPClient and I tried to upload image by

```
    let client = AFHTTPClient(baseURL:NSURL(string:"http://www.mywebsite.com/"))
    client.multipartFormRequestWithMethod(nil, path: "api/index.php/myimg", parameters: nil) { (data:AFMultipartFormData!) in
         data.appendPartWithFileData(jpegImage, name: "attachment", fileName: stringImageName, mimeType: "image/jpeg")

    }
```

and I don't get any answers regarding how to use this method.. Please help..

Comment: loosely related: Why are you using AFNetworking 1.3.3 not the latest version?

Comment: @Mr.Bista Because I need to add AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient authentication which uses AFnetworking 1.3.4 (AFHTTPClient.h) to get products from woocommerce site with help of  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37762147/6822248 ..

Comment: But there might be some new method in latest version for it.

Comment: @Mr.Bista  Do you know any other library which helps in uploading images ?

Comment: Since you are using swift, Use Swift version of AFNetwroking: Alamofire, in there git page you'll see one method which shows how to upload files.